# How can I integrate otp verification in php while signup

Tags: verification, one-time-password

I just wanted to integrate a sms otp verification method for verification while signup using msg91 not sendOTP. How can I do this kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

To verify a phone number or OTP , you need to do it in three steps :

1. When user requests OTP or you generate it, you need to store the OTP in database or in memory with that phonenumber and the user.
2. Send that OTP to mobile number using MSG91's API(http://api.msg91.com/apidoc/textsms/send-sms.php#sendcontent)
3. When user inputs the received OTP, search that in the database with phonenumber and OTP,if found verify the user stored with that phonenumber and OTP

This is generally the process.

(You can find sample code for different languages using MSG91 here : http://api.msg91.com/apidoc/samplecode/php-sample-code-send-sms.php)